# Windows CMD.exe "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: php, windows, cmd, system, exec

## Solved by restoring Windows to previous state

### The message (The system cannot find the path specified.) shows...

1) When i open new CMD (Win+R => cmd). It starts with introduction. (on line 3)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\ViliamKopecky>
```

2) When i execute some command like `cmd /C dir` (or `cmd /C php -v` or whatever) (on line 2)

```
C:\Users\ViliamKopecky>cmd /C dir
The system cannot find the path specified.
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8230-1246
...

C:\Windows\System32>cmd /C php -v
The system cannot find the path specified.
PHP 5.4.8 (cli) (built: Oct 16 2012 22:30:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

3) (the most annoying) when i run `exec` function from PHP or Node.js or probably any scripting lang. (which are probably runned from inside as `cmd /C <command>`)

### The message does not show...

1) when i execute the command right from the cmd (or mingw, ...)

```
C:\Users\ViliamKopecky>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8230-1246

 Directory of C:\Users\ViliamKopecky
```

---

Let's start with simple command from cmd.

`php -r "exec('dir', $stdout, $stderr); print(implode(\"\n\", $stdout), $stderr);"`

and the result is like this *(the directory test is empty - that is correct)*:

```
E:\test>php -r "exec('dir', $stdout, $stderr); print(implode(\"\n\", $stdout), $stderr);"
The system cannot find the path specified.
 Volume in drive E is www
 Volume Serial Number is 0C99-95EC

 Directory of E:\test

09.11.2012  22:42    <DIR>          .
09.11.2012  22:42    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  13 495 296 000 bytes free
int(1)
```

Which shows that the command `dir` has is executed from php correctly. Only thing thats wrong is the second line - **The system cannot find the path specified.** - that should not be there.

This message is output by exec from **PHP** (and also from **Node.js** as `require('child_process').exec("dir", function(err, stdout, stderr) {console.log(stderr)});`)

When I execute command right from cmd (or mingw, etc.) it executes correctly without the message. Environment variable PATH seem ok. Problem is just executing from script environment through `exec` functions.

**How to get rid of that annoying message?** Thanks

Comment: So where is the failing code?

Comment: It's the message **The system cannot find the path specified.** - in larger scripts it shows like 50 times.

Comment: Ah… Try `system` instead of `exec`?

Comment: both `system` and `shell_exec` do the same bad thing.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, Nuzzolilo, but still not much progress :-/ but thanks for trying

Comment: It's not problem of PHP. It's problem with OS.

Comment: See the comment by alvaro at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem is that some program has been set to autorun when you run cmd.exe.
In my case it was ANSICON that was installed... and then I moved the file without properly uninstalling.

I found a solution in this blog post:

http://carol-nichols.com/2011/03/17/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/

The short version is to find

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

and clear the value.

Comment: ANSICON - yes, the problem stared after I installed it. Marking your answer as accepted. Thanks ;)

Comment: 3 hours of research on where does my drush install error comes from and I ended up here after found that it failed at php exec, and yes it was ANSICON +1

Comment: Make sure you check HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun as well. Particularly if you have Clink.

Comment: Excellent find! I got a problem using **node.js and npm** because there was some script launching from Autorun that returned error code 1 and some stderr output. After redirecting stderr `> nul 2>&1` and adding `exit /b 0` at the end of the script it works now!

Comment: Actually, do a search throughout the registry for 'command processor' and check value of AutoRun. Clink for me put it in some bizarre places and still wouldn't work. But this did fix the OP issue. Woohoo !

Comment: Thank you! I I had a leftover conda intializing hook that was producing this error and producing side effects somewhere really far away. Took me a while to track it down until I finally got here!

Comment: Thank you. you save my time. I already spent 4 hours to solve it.

Comment: In my case, it was `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` instead of `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

Comment: Also had a removed Conda installation popping this issue in CMD - I was so free to add a comment here https://superuser.com/questions/727316/error-in-command-line-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified as well

Answer (score 2):

This message can mean a path in the `PATH` enviromental variable doesn't exist.

The following PowerShell command will print missing paths.

```
($env:path).Trim(";").Split(";") | ? {-not (test-path $_)}
```

e.g.

```
> ($env:path).Trim(";").Split(";") | ? {-not (test-path $_)}
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
C:\Program Files\SDCC\bin
C:\Users\wjbr\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

References

- http://carol-nichols.com/2011/03/17/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/
- https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/the-system-cannot-find-path-specified-error-in-command-prompt.html

Answer (score 0):

This actually looks like a startup error with PHP, not with your code.  Does

`php -r "echo 1;"`

also throw the same error?  If so, your php.ini file or an include may be pathed incorrectly.

`php -i`

should give you more info.

Comment: This runs correctly
`C:\Users\ViliamKopecky>php -r "echo 1;"
1`

Answer (score -3):

I think you should try this out ! I had the same issue and solved it like this :

ok type : cd\windows\system32
After that you will see this:    System32/:
Type what you want (ex:ipconfig):
System32: ipconfig 
Then that should do it ! 
:)