# Powershell "The system cannot find the path specified" - minium example

Tags: powershell

Not reproducible, seems local environment problem:

bla.bat file with the following contend:

```
@echo off
```

So this script should actuall do nothing at all. Now, when trying to execute the script from PowerShell, the following is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\lwnjup2> .\bla.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

wheras in CMD the bat-file executes as excepted (doing nothing...).

So my question: why this strange warning? Is there a way, how I can get more ouput (i.e. what path cannot be found)? To me it looks, as if PowerShell searches always for some path, when executing any .bat (or .cmd) file.

PS: Strangely I cannot reproduce behaviour on a different machine, so it seems I have messed up my powershell environment...

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: From that console, can you run `Get-ChildItem env:` and let me know the value of `ComSpec` variable?

Comment: @AdminOfThings there I have C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: @AdminOfThings okay, very interesting: when executing "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" from powershell, I get:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.316]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden."

Comment: Thanks for hinting me to cmd.exe, resolution found and posted.

Answer (score 2):

Resolution was related to cmd.exe and found in

[Windows CMD.exe "The system cannot find the path specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316682/windows-cmd-exe-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)

I also had some autostart value...