# "The system cannot find the path specified" in prompt after conda 4.6 to 4.5 downgrade

Tags: conda

I am getting "The system cannot find the path specified" in the anaconda prompt and when I run cmd.exe.

I recently downgraded from conda 4.6 to 4.5.

(Posted here to point out this is happening due to conda).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows CMD.exe "The system cannot find the path specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316682/windows-cmd-exe-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13343337/4893407

Go to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun and clear the value.

Mine was trying to run conda_hook.bat which no longer exists due to downgrading to 4.5.